# "Search-UnifiedAuditLog" will only return 100 items , any advice how we can expand this?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have the following script which i tailored from this link https://www.easy365manager.com/office-365-forensics-using-powershell-and-search-unifiedauditlog/ to get the audit logs for 2 SharePoint sites

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline
$SiteIDs = '64898c8f-2d5f-4e0e-9a9b-eb9828975a9e','20e6140c-0441-4988-b36c-c61cf3400847'
$Operations = @('FileAccessed','FileDownloaded','FileDeleted')
$OutputFile = ".\UnifiedAuditLog_FULL.csv"
$Today = Get-Date -Date (Get-Date -Format “yyyy-MM-dd”)
$intDays = 14
For ($i=0; $i -le $intDays; $i++){
  For ($j=23; $j -ge 0; $j--){
    $StartDate = ($Today.AddDays(-$i)).AddHours($j)
    $EndDate = ($Today.AddDays(-$i)).AddHours($j + 1)
    $Audit = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate -SessionId "WordDocs_SharepointViews 123444" -SessionCommand ReturnLargeSet -SiteIds $SiteIDs -RecordType SharePointFileOperation -Operations $Operations 
    $ConvertAudit = $Audit | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AuditData | ConvertFrom-Json
    $OutputFile0 = ".\UnifiedAuditLog_FULL"+$i+$j+"ALL2.csv"
    $ConvertAudit | Select-Object CreationTime,UserId,Operation,Workload,ObjectID,SiteUrl,SourceFileName,ClientIP,UserAgent | Export-Csv $OutputFile0 -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
    Write-Host $StartDate `t $Audit.Count
  }
}
Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

now i will only get 100 items on each call to the `Search-UnifiedAuditLog`.. now since i am using those parameters `-SessionId "WordDocs_SharepointViews 123444" -SessionCommand ReturnLargeSet`  i should get up to 50,000 results based on this documentation @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/search-unifiedauditlog?view=exchange-ps#-sessioncommand

any advice why i am only getting 100 items?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the parameter `-ResultSize`

The ResultSize parameter specifies the maximum number of results to return. The default value is 100, maximum is 5,000.

the parameter is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/search-unifiedauditlog?view=exchange-ps

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the reply.. so in this case what is the purpose of those 2 parameters `-SessionId`  & `-SessionCommand`?

Comment: Just by reading the documentation I assume you could only use this parameter, but then you have to use paging to get more results. And the ResultSize is just the number of results you get for each page. But I'm just guessing, never used this command.